# Multiple quotes from same company

Tags: professionalism, ethics

I am currently in the process of getting quotes for a new access control system at my place of employment. One of the companies has the system we would like to use but my experiences with the sale rep (personal connection to company) have been less than stellar.

For example:

-Having to ask for the quote to be amended multiple times due to leaving things off we asked for

-Not wanting to walk premise and just asking how many doors

-Previous bad install from this sales associate

-Constantly asking to see full quotes from competitors to make sure he is competitive

-Feels like they are low balling quote just to get in door and then will have constant up sales for things that will be needed

I have another point of contact at the same company and was considering reaching out to that individual to have them come out and give a quote and see if the experience is better but I feel like that is in bad taste and probably shouldn't be done.

Just looking for a little input to see what others think as this is the first time I have really had to deal with this type of issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think this is a 'Workplace' related issue, the question being asked is how to deal with a 3rd party vendor.

Comment: I understand it may be difficult to know where to ask such questions, but this isn't really a question suitable for The Workplace, but maybe I can provide an answer with a workplace feel.

Comment: A short workplace answer: Ask your boss this question. Only your boss can make the decision. You do have a boss, don't you?

Answer (score 5):

A Workplace answer:

First and foremost, you have an obligation to your employer to do the best job possible.

If you think that going to the second contact would yield a better outcome, then that is exactly what you should do.

Make sure you are up-front and honest about the situation with your second contact, so you don't burn a bridge with them by putting them in an awkward position. (Which would lead to worse outcomes in the future).